# How to tell if TinyMCE is initiated/created on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have a page with a canvas where a user can add text with the "add text" button. When the user clicks this, a new TinyMCE is created right on the canvas. I would like to change this new TinyMCE, but because I cannot access the tinyMCE creation code (the init) I got to have some kind of "on init listener" for TinyMCE in my `document.ready()'.

I know you can make a callback on init of the TinyMCE like this:

```
setup: function (ed) {
    ed.on('init', function(args) {
        console.debug(args.target.id);
    });
}
```

But as I said I can't reach the creation code of the TinyMCE.

How can I check whether a new TinyMCE instance has been created (and use it in Javascript)?

Comment: So what exactly are you wanting to do once you know that TinyMCE is created?  The function you mention is indeed the easiest way to know when TinyMCE is ready ... but I would be interested to know what you want to do that cannot be done via this API hook.

Comment: I'd like to change the toolbar when the tinyMCE is ready. Keep in mind that I am not able to change the TinyMCE init configuriations, so I can't use the function I described in my question.

Comment: TinyMCE does not allow you to change the toolbar once the editor is loaded.  Even if you cannot directly modify the init object you can always use JavaScript to modify the init object before you actually invoke TinyMCE with it.

Comment: Allright, thanks for your clarification. Could you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: I created an answer with the details ... too much to put in as a comment.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your page provides you a configuration object but you want to tweak its settings, you can always use JavaScript to modify/extend your standard init on a page by page basis.

For example, start with your standard configuration:

```
baseConfig = {
    selector: 'textarea'
    ....
}
```

...since this is just a simple JavaScript object you can inject additional properties/methods into that object before you use it to initialize TinyMCE.

For example:

```
 customConfig = {
    image_advtab: true,
    content_css : "CSS/content.css?"  + new Date().getTime(),
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('init', function () {
            //Do what you need to do once TinyMCE is initialized
        });
    }
}
```

Then you can "inject" `customConfig` into `baseConfig`.  The easiest way is to use jQuery's extend method:

```
$.extend(baseConfig, customConfig);
```

...this will take all the methods and properties from `customConfig` and add them to `baseConfig`.  Once you are done you can then load TinyMCE using the newly updated `baseConfig`:

```
tinymce.init(baseConfig);
```

You can also use JavaScript to remove properties (read up on the `delete`) so you could also remove configuration properties that you don't want in your TinyMCE init.